# mongodb aggregation and using $group to sum and fetch out all the data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

here is the sample data
**col1**

```
  {  "_id" : ObjectId("5ed6ba752eed7210244bf6c5"),
                "buyerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b8cc74fd0601cccc96d1"),
                "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"),
                 "boughtOnDate" : ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z"),
                  "weekDay" : "wed",
                  "itemDescription" : [
                                {
                                    "numberOfItems": 10,
                                    "freeAttachments": 2,
                                    "itemName": "item1",
                                    "itemCode": "it001",

                                },
                                {
                                    "numberOfItems": 15,
                                    "freeAttachments": 1,
                                    "itemName": "item2",
                                    "itemCode": "it002",
                                }
                            ],

}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed6ba752eed7210244bf6c2"),
               "buyerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b8cc74fd0601cccc96d0"),
                "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"),
                "boughtOnDate" : ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z"),
                 "weekDay" : "wed",
                 "itemDescription" : [
                                {
                                    "numberOfItems": 20,
                                    "freeAttachments": 2,
                                    "itemName": "item1",
                                    "itemCode": "it001",

                                },
                                {
                                    "numberOfItems": 15,
                                    "freeAttachments": 1,
                                    "itemName": "item2",
                                    "itemCode": "it002",
                                }
                            ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed6ba752eed7210244bffc7"),
                "buyerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b8cc74fd0601cccc96d1"),
                "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"),
                 "boughtOnDate" : ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z"),
                 "weekDay" : "tue",
                 "itemDescription" : [
                                {
                                    "numberOfItems": 10,
                                    "freeAttachments": 2,
                                    "itemName": "item1",
                                    "itemCode": "it001",

                                },
                                {
                                    "numberOfItems": 15,
                                    "freeAttachments": 1,
                                    "itemName": "item2",
                                    "itemCode": "it002",
                                }
                            ],

}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed6ba752eed7210244bf6bf"),
                "buyerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b8cc74fd0601cccc96d0"),
                "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"),
                "boughtOnDate" : ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z"),
                 "weekDay" : "tue",
                 "itemDescription" : [
                                {
                                    "numberOfItems": 10,
                                    "freeAttachments": 2,
                                    "itemName": "item1",
                                    "itemCode": "it001",

                                },
                                {
                                    "numberOfItems": 15,
                                    "freeAttachments": 1,
                                    "itemName": "item2",
                                    "itemCode": "it002",
                                }
                            ]
}
```

**col2:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed6ba762eed7210244bf6cf"),
    "bill" : 40,
   "buyerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b8cc74fd0601cccc96d1"),
    "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z"),

}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed6ba762eed7210244bf6ce"),
   "bill" : 20,
     "buyerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b8cc74fd0601cccc96d0"),
    "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z"),

}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed6ba762eed7210244bf6cd"),
    "bill" : 30,
    "buyerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b8cc74fd0601cccc96d1"),
    "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z"),

}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed6ba762eed7210244bf6be"),
   "bill" : 60,
    "buyerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b8cc74fd0601cccc96d0"),
    "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z"),

}
```

problem statement: I need to sumup `"numberOfItems"` as totalNumberOfItems  and `"freeAttachments` as totalFreeAttachments from col1 for each date i.e in result i should get 1 document for `boughtOnDate:ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z")` and 1 document for `"boughtOnDate" : ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z")` also i need calculate `bill`as totalBill from col2 against the `sellerId` from col1 according to dates.In result i need to show the `sellerId,weekday,itemName,boughtOnDate,totalNumberOfItems,totalFreeAttachments,totalBill`
Now **this what i have tried so far**

```
db.col1.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {

        "sellerId": ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"),

        "boughtOnDate": {
            $lte: ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z"),
            $gte: ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z")
        },
    }

}, { '$unwind': '$itemDescription' }, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'col2',
        let: {
            buyerId: '$buyerId',
            sellerId: "$sellerId",
            date: '$boughtOnDate'
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [

                            {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$sellerId",
                                    "$$sellerId"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$buyerId",
                                    "$$buyerId"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $eq: [
                                    "$date",
                                    "$$date"
                                ]
                            },

                        ]
                    }
                }
            },

        ],
        as: 'col2'
    }
}, { '$unwind': '$col2' },
{
    $group:
    {
        _id: {
            'date': '$boughtOnDate',
            'sellerId': '$sellerId',

        },
        totalBill: {
            '$sum':
                '$col2.bill'
        },
        totalNumberOfItems: {
            '$sum':
                '$col1.numberOfItems'
        },
        totalFreeAttachments: {
            '$sum':
                '$col1.freeAttachments'
        },

    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
       boughtOnDate: 1,
         totalNumberOfItems: 1,
        totalFreeAttachments: 1,
    itemName: '$col1.itemName',
        weekDay: 1,
        totalBill: 1
    }
}])
```

**but i am unable to get weekDay,itemName,boughtOnDate in the projection**.Any suggestions what do i need to do to achieve the expected result

---

**Expected Output:**

```
{ 

"boughtOnDate" : ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z"), 
"sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"), 
"totalNumberOfItems" : 50, "totalFreeAttachments" : 6, 
"weekday":"tue" 
} 
{ 
"boughtOnDate" : ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z"), 
"sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101"), 
"totalNumberOfItems" : 50, 
"totalFreeAttachments" : 6, 
"weekday":"wed" 
}
```

Comment: Can you post what the expected output from the above collection data and the aggregation - after the group stage.

Comment: @prasad sure {
    "_id" : {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z"),
            "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101")
    },
    "totalNumberOfItems" : 50,
    "totalFreeAttachments" : 6,
    
}
{
    "_id" : {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z"),
            "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101")
    },
    "totalNumberOfItems" : 50,
    "totalFreeAttachments" : 6,
   
}

Comment: @sorry i put the wrong date in the question :`"boughtOnDate": {
            $lte: ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z"),
            $gte: ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z")
        },`, i have corrected that its 03 now though result after $group is correct

Comment: What does the expected output document look like?

Comment: @prasad--{
    
            "boughtOnDate" : ISODate("2020-06-02T00:00:00Z"),
            "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101")
    "totalNumberOfItems" : 50,
    "totalFreeAttachments" : 6,
    "weekday":"tue"
    
}
{
  
            "boughtOnDate" : ISODate("2020-06-03T00:00:00Z"),
            "sellerId" : ObjectId("5ed0b944389c6a0f948eb101")
 "totalNumberOfItems" : 50,
    "totalFreeAttachments" : 6,
    "weekday":"wed"
} this is what i am trying to get

Comment: I added the expected output to your post. I just ran your aggregation. After the _first_ `$match` stage there are no documents selected.

Comment: @ prasad lets chat